# Qt6 Ошибка сборки из исходников 2

Tags: build-error, qt6

Пытаюсь собрать из исходников версию 6.4.0
Выдает следующие ошибки:

```
[ 42%] Building CXX object qttools/src/qdoc/CMakeFiles/qdoc.dir/helpprojectwriter.cpp.o
In file included from   
/home/****/Development/Qt/Static/6.4.0/Src/qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/lupdatepreprocessoraction.cpp:4:
/home/****/Development/Qt/Static/6.4.0/Src/qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/lupdatepreprocessoraction.h:52:10: 
ошибка: «void LupdatePPCallbacks::InclusionDirective(clang::SourceLocation, const clang::Token&, llvm::StringRef, bool, clang::CharSourceRange, const clang::FileEntry*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, const clang::Module*, clang::SrcMgr::CharacteristicKind)» помечен «override», но не делается override
52 |     void InclusionDirective(clang::SourceLocation /*hashLoc*/, const clang::Token &/*includeTok*/,
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from
/home/****/Development/Qt/Static/6.4.0/Src/qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/cpp_clang.cpp:7
:/home/****/Development/Qt/Static/6.4.0/Src/qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/lupdatepreprocessoraction.h:52:10: ошибка: «void LupdatePPCallbacks::InclusionDirective(clang::SourceLocation, const clang::Token&, llvm::StringRef, bool, clang::CharSourceRange, const clang::FileEntry*, llvm::StringRef, llvm::StringRef, const clang::Module*,     clang::SrcMgr::CharacteristicKind)» 
помечен «override», но не делается override
52 |     void InclusionDirective(clang::SourceLocation /*hashLoc*/, const clang::Token &/*includeTok*/,
  |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[ 42%] Building CXX object qttools/src/qdoc/CMakeFiles/qdoc.dir/htmlgenerator.cpp.o
gmake[2]: *** [qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/CMakeFiles/lupdate.dir/build.make:412: qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/CMakeFiles/lupdate.dir/lupdatepreprocessoraction.cpp.o] Ошибка 1
gmake[2]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
```

и

```
[ 42%] Building CXX object qttools/src/qdoc/CMakeFiles/qdoc.dir/main.cpp.o
gmake[2]: *** [qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/CMakeFiles/lupdate.dir/build.make:384:     qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/CMakeFiles/lupdate.dir/cpp_clang.cpp.o] Ошибка 1
gmake[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:65283:     qttools/src/linguist/lupdate/CMakeFiles/lupdate.dir/all] Ошибка 2
gmake[1]: *** Ожидание завершения заданий…
```

как с этим бороться?